# Limit number of results from 3-table join

Tags: sql-server, join, greatest-n-per-group, multiple-tables

I have 3 tables: SWPPP_SITE, SWPPP_TRACKING, and LKUP_CONSTRUCTION_STATUS.

The SWPPP_SITE is 1:many with SWPPP_TRACKING. The SWPPP_SITE is 1:1 with LKUP_CONSTRUCTION_STATUS.

I'm trying to select 1 record for a unique site for all sites. This query gives me multiple records for each site -- 1 site, many tracking, and the corresponding status.

How can I retrieve only e.g. one record for Test_1 and one for Test_site3, per the image?

```
SELECT s.OBJECTID As SITE_OID, s.Site_Name AS SITE_Site_Name, 
    s.Construction_StatusID, t.OBJECTID As TRACKING_OID, t.Site_Name As 
    TRACKING_Site_Name, cs.OBJECTID As CON_STAT_OID, cs.Status
FROM SWPPP_SITE s INNER JOIN SWPPP_TRACKING t ON s.Site_Name = t.Site_Name
INNER JOIN LKUP_CONSTRUCTION_STATUS cs ON s.Construction_StatusID = 
    cs.OBJECTID
WHERE t.Completion_Date Between '1/1/18' And '5/1/18';
```

[image]

Comment: If you only want one row per site, which row from tracking do you want?

Comment: Remove those unnecessary brackets. Why do you bracket everything??  It makes it hard to read.

Comment: Also learn to use table alias.  The long table names is very annoying to read.

Comment: Tab is spot on. You're getting multiple records because there are multiple tracking records for each site; for example, site 21 has two tracking records 46 and 47.

Comment: OK. The site info is the same, say for site 21 across tracking records 46 and 47. Note: a superset of these data are going into a report, hence the need to eliminate duplicate sites.

Answer (score 1):

you can just SELECT DISTINCT..., and only include the columns that you care about (i.e., remove TRACKING_OID)